# Checking/removing SKScene sprite children easily/efficiently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Working on an iOS game using SpriteKit. My background is made up of map tiles (essentially an infinite map, procedurally generated).

Our system is designed to manage "chunks" of the map, and we only load chunks near the player. Since SpriteKit requires we add `SKSpriteNodes`, we no longer have clean control over "unloading" sprites for chunks/tiles that are no longer near the player.

I realize SpriteKit won't actually render things off-screen, but it's going to kill performance if we can't remove sprites no longer needed, or check if a chunk/tile is already added.

Since `SKNodes` doesn't respond to `isEqual:`, I only see two ways to do this:

- Give each sprite a name with their chunk/tile coordinate, and check this name each update
- Maintain a separate array of loaded tiles and check that instead

Is there any easier way of checking/removing if a sprite has been added already? Maybe a partial string match on sprite name?

I'm not sure that using SpriteKit is the best solution (Xcode simulator seems to drag at 30fps, have yet to test on a real device). We originally built this game in Java and we're rendering our own textures - hence only what was loaded and could be fed into opengl manually.

```
-(void) renderToScene:(SKScene *)scene {

    for( Chunk *chunk in loadedChunks ){
        for( Tile *tile in [chunk getTiles] ){

            SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:tileTexture];
            sprite.name = @"Tile";
            sprite.position = CGPointMake(realX,realY);
            [scene addChild:sprite];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What will in fact kill your framerate is frequently creating and removing nodes - you should have a pool of sprites that you re-use rather than recreate.

Just update the sprite's texture, position and other attributes when reusing one of those you no longer need. A common use case is to have enough tiles to span the entire screen plus one row and one column, so that when an entire row or column has moved outside the screen you can reposition it at the other side with new textures according to the map data.

Comment: Would constant sprite update for the tile locations use a lot of processing power on iOS devices?

Comment: Guessing is not my forte, not even sure what you mean by that. But certainly the create/add/remove/dealloc node cycle isn't particularly fast and definitely noticably slower than reusing nodes no matter which and how many properties of the node you change. On iOS your primary goal should be to avoid alloc/dealloc cycles as much as possible, and disk access. The CPUs are quite fast, but memory and storage aren't, and older devices (iPhone 4, iPad 1) also have significantly slower GPUs.

Comment: As the player moves around this could be a very frequent change and "recycling" sprite nodes still seems like a lot of work. It will essentially require synchronizing nodes in the "pool" with tiles we actually have loaded. I'm wondering if I should skip doing this in SpiteKit and do it directly in opengl. Every cycle of our java version simply batch renders loaded tiles. There's no middle man of mirroring the tiles with an array of nodes.

Comment: I believe you're overthinking this. You are going to load all of the tile textures into memory, so you don't need to worry about what texture is loaded and what isn't (and because loading textures is slow, best avoided during gameplay). There's no need to synchronize, you simply need to know what the lower-left (or other corner) tile's coordinates are and you can derive each tile's coordinates from that, for displaying it or for getting tile info from the map.

Comment: ...but how would you remove a node? Even though it's not efficient - how do you do it? self.removeFromParent() isn't working for me

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding what you're asking correctly. You want to properly remove a node/sprite from the scene if its no longer within view.

You should just be able to call the [self removeFromParent] method to remove in whenever its outside the bounds of the screen. Remember you can call this method on any object as long as its a child.

For instance if i had character,

SKSpriteNode *character;
SKSpriteNode *sword;

//all the rest of the properties are up to you.

if my character picked up a sword in the game and after a certain time period the sword is no longer accessible. I would do:

[character addChild:sword];
which would add it to the character.

[sword removeFromParent];
when i no longer need the sword to be apart of its parent.